# Pass data to middleware further down the chain

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, middleware

When I register middleware as part of the request pipeline, how do I pass data through the middleware chain. (ultimately accessible in an MVC controller action)

For example, I have implemented custom middleware for authenticating my requests, but how can I pass the authentication data (such as the result of the authentication and additional data) down the chain of middleware - ultimately wanting to access the data from an MVC controller action, and also in a custom MVC action filter for restricting access based on the authentication results.

Is there anywhere I can store custom data on a per-request basis, and access it later in the request chain?

Comment: If you want to add extra claims to current principal(as far as i understand your example), you can use `Claims Transformation`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can use the `HttpContext.Items` collection to store data for the lifetime of a request. Its primary use-case is passing data around components (middleware and controllers for example). Adding and reading items is easy:

Write:

```
context.Items["AuthData"] = authData;
```

Read:

```
var authData = (AuthData)context.Items["AuthData"];
```

See the [ASP.NET docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/app-state.html#httpcontext-items) for more info.

Comment: I knew it existed, just couldn't find it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can store custom data in [IOwinContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.iowincontext(v=vs.113).aspx) object. IOwinContext object can be accessed from Invoke function of your middleware.

Set

```
context.Set<T>("key", obj);
```

Get

```
var obj = context.Get<T>("key");
```